# how can I download only first 10 kilobyte of a file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js how can I download specific amount of file, like only first 10 kilobyte of a file.

in my project, I need to extract mp3 duration and bitrate from remote file and the only way I think is download just a few bytes to the entire file.

As some guy said [here](http://www.getid3.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=842) If you download (at least) the first 32kB of the file you should be OK for most MP3 files.

Comment: start download, listen to data events, keep track of how many bytes you've read and abort after 10kb

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum do you have any example ,i'm a newbie in node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node.js you know when a chunk of data is available. If you do a http request you are given a response object which contains the headers. This response object is also a stream with events. The one you are searching for is `"data"`. With this event you get a buffer filled with the data received (only the new data, the previously received chunks are not present). You just have to have a buffer and append to it each time you get a chunk of data. You can also get the length of the buffer. You can choose to stop downloading the data when you have enough data using the method `destroy` method. Here is an example :

```
var http = require("http");
var buff = new Buffer(0);
http.get("http://epfl.ch", function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buff = Buffer.concat([buff, chunk]);
        if (buff.length > 10240) {
            res.destroy();
            console.log(buff);
        }
    });
})
```

this code will wait to fetch 10kb bytes then end the request. Then you can dou whatever you want with the data (buff)

If you want to save the data to file while downloading you can do this instead :

```
var http = require("http");
var buff = new Buffer(0);
var fs = require("fs");

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.mp3");

http.get("http://epfl.ch", function(res) {
    res.pipe(file);
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buff = Buffer.concat([buff, chunk]);
        if (buff.length > 10240) {
            res.destroy();
            file.close();
            console.log(buff);
        }
    });
})
```

This code will create an input stream for a file and pipe the body of the request to this file (ie. each chunk of data received will be append to the file).

If you don't want to do anything with your buffer you don't need to keep it you can just count the number of bytes received and stop when you need.

```
var http = require("http");
var bytesRecieved = 0;
var fs = require("fs");

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.mp3");

    http.get("http://epfl.ch", function(res) {
        res.pipe(file);
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {               
            bytesRecieved += chunk.length;
            if (bytesRecieved > 10240) {
                res.destroy();
                file.close();
            }
        });
    })
```

Best regards,

Comment: thanks ,if fetch 10kb of mp3 file , for extraxting duration and bitrate i need save to new file and than use id3js ?

Comment: Hi @DARK_DUCK , I have a question.